# Why is $g_n:=\inf\{f_n,f_{n+1},...\}$ integrable if $f_n$ are?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

This question is motivated by the proof of the [Fatou's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma).

My text defines $g_n:=\inf\{f_n,f_{n+1},\ldots\}$ and states that it's Lebesgue integrable (each $f_n$ is). We proved that point-wise minimum of any two integrable functions is integrable. How can this be extended to this case?

**Update**:

After the two answers, it turned out that our ways of introducing the integration theory is not very conventional: we haven't had Borel sets yet.

Could some manipulation with minimum of finite amount do the job?

Say, we define $g_{n,m}:=\min\{f_n,\ldots,f_m\}$. Then $g_{n,m}\searrow g_n$ for $m \to \infty$ and we're done with the monotone convergence theorem. Would it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that, for every $a\in\mathbb R$
$$
g_n^{-1}(-\infty,a)=\bigcup_{m\ge n}f_m^{-1}(-\infty,a).
$$
The right hand side is a measurable set, as a countable union of measurable sets, while the left hand side, spans, for different values of $a$ all the inverses of Borel sets by $g_n$. Hence, all the $g_n$'s are measurable.

Comment: Clarification: This is for Lebesgue integrability

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Please take a look at the update.